# Why is (equal (copy-<some struct type> <struct type object>) <same struct type object>) nil?

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable, equality

The elements of the struct type are s-expressions.

```
(defstruct state
  homeS
  homeH
  homeD
  homeC
  free
  stacks)
```

I was attempting to use these objects as keys to a hash table.  Before I converted to a struct and was using a deeper S-expression, all worked well.  When I changed to a defstruct, the hash table never succeeded with finding a duplicate key.

The hashtable was made with `(make-hash-table :test #'equal)`, so I looked at the the behavior of equal.

I expected `(equal (copy-state state1) state1)` to return t, but it returned nil.

I haven't found this in the Common Lisp Hyper-Specification.  I think the answer is to write my own test and hash functions, and give them to make-hash-table.

This must be defined as common lisp behavior -- it works the same way in CLISP and SBCL.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Common Lisp Hyper Specification, the natural operation "equal", does not work with structured data like defstruct and defarray objects.

In this case, for objects defined by a defstruct type the "equal" operator does not work, and a different operator, "equalp", is used to compare structured data.